# Return drive letter for findfile in vim script?

Tags: vim

I use `findfile()` function in Vim to retrieve the full path of a file. It seems the returned path (if found) doesn't include drive letter (and `:`, like `c:`) on **Windows** so it might have some issue to use this path . Is there a way to get driver letter for the returned path, or a dedicated function can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path returned by `findfile()` is correct with regards to the current working directory, so as long as you don't change that, using it directly should be fine.

If you need to switch buffers or do other things that might affect the CWD, you can expand the filespec into a full absolute form via:

```
let absoluteFilespec = fnamemodify(findfile(...), ':p')
```